# How to display contact name in MIT App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

Could you help me to find out how I will get and display contact name.

I am able to get and display the contact number only, but what I need is to get the data of contact name via contact number saved on the phone. This is for my school project purposes.

I am using MIT App inventor. What should I do?

> [Here is a screenshot of my blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unkn7.png)
>   [image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Ayzs! Could you add the code you have written so far (even if it's not working)? It's much easier for users to answer a question based on an existing code snippet.

Comment: I just posted the picture of the blocks i made :)

Answer (score 0):

The texting component does not provide that information. As you can see, you can only get the `number` and the `message text`.

To get the contact name, you could use the [Read Contact Extension](https://community.thunkable.com/t/read-contact-extension-paid-extension/7380?u=taifun) by Andres Daniel. Note: this is a paid extension.

For a list of available extensions, see https://puravidaapps.com/extensions.php